# Do people really read parallax scrolling homepages?

Tags: website-design, web, homepage, structure

First, let me define what I mean by parallax scrolling homepage with a few examples:

- Google's Nexus 5: http://www.google.com/nexus/5/
- Sony USA: http://discover.store.sony.com/be-moved/
- Koa Water: http://www.drinkkoa.com

It tells the user a story, letting the user scroll through the story at their own pace.

Personally, I find these kinds of pages bothersome and just quickly scroll to the bottom, hoping to get to the end, but this got me to wonder about a few questions:

1. Do people really read the content on these kinds of pages?
2. How does it fare when compared to a static page that tries to drive the same point?
3. Does it have any advantages over 'traditional' homepages?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "traditional" homepage? A wall of text with some spec tables sprinkled around?

Comment: @LieRyan of course not, I mean a homepage that uses other means to tell the product's story.

Comment: A 'traditional' home page = 2 minute flash intro. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the examples you have quoted are **examples of parallax sites which use shifting content to tell and story and keep the user engaged**.I am going to break this response into three parts.

### **The reasoning**

I would recommend looking at [this article for additional inputs on how parallax sites keep users engaged.](http://blog.usabilla.com/15-reasons-why-parallax-scrolling-in-web-design-is-awesome/)

> **Storytelling**
>
> Parallax scrolling offers the ideal setting to tell your story in an
>   engaging and interactive way. Let your visitors take control and let
>   them walk through your story in their own pace. The different layers
>   that respond differently to the scrolling behaviour of your visitors
>   create a sense of depth and even allow for multiple story lines.
>
> **Make your visitors curious**
>
> [image]
>
> The drink Michelberger Booze engages you as a visitor in a very
>   creative way. At the very top of the site it says: “Just scroll down
>   gently… When your glass is empty, click to feel the booze.” What is
>   the booze? When scrolling down the page, you see an artistic still
>   life setting. When scrolling further, two things happen. The watch
>   hands rotate and the drink disappears. Then a mask appears which, when
>   clicking on it, leads you to the booze — a beautiful, animated
>   illustration that represents the sphere of the drink. Only at the very
>   end of the site, you get the actual information about the drink.
>   Still, there is almost no way to get there without engaging with the
>   site first.
>
> **Let your visitors have some fun**
>
> Another great example of how to engage your visitors is the site of
>   the KRYSTALRAE fall collection. Different outfits are presented on one
>   and the same model. The design is very minimalistic, focussing all
>   attention on the model and the dog in the center of the page. When
>   scrolling down the page, you can change the outfit yourself, while the
>   rest of the scene stays the same. This interaction is simple, but fun
>   and very engaging.
>
> [image]
>
> **Surprise your visitors**
>
> You can also use parallax scrolling to surprise your visitors. For
>   example, on the Japanese website of the Nissan Note, you get an entire
>   story about the car, when scrolling down the page. This already makes
>   it a special experience. However, once you are at the bottom of the
>   site, there is a link that says: “Try Reverse!” The site automatically
>   scrolls back to the top, giving you yet another version of the story.

### **The study\Research**

That said,**there is no concrete information which shows that a simple site vs a parallax site would perform poorer** except for [this study which showed that the user journey was similar for users on both sites except they found these parallax scrolling sites to be more fun](http://www.fastcodesign.com/3023690/evidence/snow-fail-do-readers-really-prefer-parallax-web-design) :

> So Frederick [set up a study of his own.](http://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgttheses/27/) He designed two hotel
>   websites similar in every way, from content to color scheme, except
>   that one featured parallax scrolling and one did not. Frederick then
>   intercepted 86 people in the lobby of the Stewart Center, a main
>   gathering point on Purdue's campus, and brought them to a computer
>   where they engaged with either the standard site or the parallax site
>   (screenshot below).
>
> The test itself didn't last very long. Participants spent a few
>   minutes getting familiar with whichever site they'd been assigned.
>   They entered demographic information into a web form. (They all
>   experienced a site error, too, because Frederick wanted to incorporate
>   the unruly nature of web use.) They made a hotel reservation. Finally
>   they rated the site on a questionnaire crafted from prior web
>   research.
>
> Frederick's survey focused on five areas of the user experience:
>   usability, enjoyment, fun, satisfaction, and visual appeal. (Enjoyment
>   and fun, while ostensibly similar metrics, differed in that a site
>   like IMDb can be enjoyable without being fun in the way a video game
>   site might be.) Before he tallied the results, Frederick was convinced
>   the parallax site would blow its opponent away.
>
> "I've read from many blogs how people say it's going to attract users
>   and create so much of a better user experience," Frederick tells
>   Co.Design. "I thought it was going to be superior to a typical website
>   in every aspect."
>
> As it happens, the **parallax site was only superior in one
>   sense--fun**. None of the other survey measures indicated a
>   significant difference in user experience between the two sites.
>   Parallax didn't even edge the standard site in questions about visual
>   appeal (although participants did think it looked slightly more
>   "professional"). Frederick also discovered one critical disadvantage
>   of parallax: test participants who suffered from motion sickness found
>   the style disorienting.

### **Conclusion**

1. **Do people really read the content on these kinds of pages?** - There is no comprehensive data on this but the higher levels of engagement would perhaps ensure the users do go through all the content
2. **How does it fare when compared to a static page that tries to drive the same point?** - As per the above mentioned study, there is not much difference in conversion, but there are obviously higher levels of engagement
3. **Does it have any advantages over 'traditional' homepages?** - Higher levels of engagement and potentially higher levels of conversion.

Comment: -1 an article that has "x reasons" and "is awesome" as its title is not one I'd trust as empirical evidence. In fact, that's mostly just a 'this is cool' type of opinion piece. That is fine, but not something I feel we should be quoting as UX research by any means.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're asking only one question.

Regardless of the type of landing page, the answer is: it depends. The reading time and conversion greatly depend on the source, the overall linking strategy, the number of visits and many other parameters.

Usually lots of A/B testing and copywriting efforts go into the final design of these landing pages.

So yes, we can assume that visitors spend more time on these pages and that they have a higher conversion rate.